# Is the --MM-DD format for month-day part of ISO 8601?

Tags: date, datetime, iso8601, java-time

The Java 8 date/time API, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), has a [MonthDay class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) to represent a month and a day together. So too the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library offers a [MonthDay](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/MonthDay.html) class.

In java.time, the `MonthDay.toString()` method is declared as:

> Outputs this month-day as a String, such as --12-03.

Most of the classes in java.time have their `toString()` method output the standard ISO 8601 representation of the concept they represent (`YYYY-MM-DD` for `LocalDate`, for example), so I would expect this `--MM-DD` format to be standard as well.

But I could not find this in the ISO 8601 standard.

**Is *month-day* a concept defined by ISO 8601, and if so, is `--MM-DD` the standard format?**

*Background: I'm developing a date/time API in another language.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in paragraph 4.4, ISO 8601:1988 says:

> Note - The hyphen is also used to indicate omitted components

So the format `--MM-DD` conforms to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), where the year is omitted/missing, and paragraph 5.2.1.3d also contains an example of that very format.

This format disappeared in later editions of the ISO 8601 standard. However, the java.time classes continue to support the format along with the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class.

Comment: While I see your second quote (5.2.1.3d) in the earlier “ISO 8601:2000(E)” second edition (draft copy), I do not see any mention of either of your quoted sections in the later “ISO 8601:2004(E)” third edition (draft copy). In the third edition, there seems to be no mention of such truncated values. Can you cite *precisely* the edition of the standard you reference?

Comment: Done. It's part of the ISO 8601 first edition 1988-06-15 version

Comment: Why did this mention disappear from recent versions of the standard? Is this format still up-to-date?

Comment: ISO-8601 has changed over the years. I don't know why. As identified, this was a valid format, and still makes sense as a toString().

Comment: Note that it is also defined this way in [`gMonthDay` of the XML Schema Definition (XSD) spec.](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#gMonthDay)